# Magento 2 View-able product

Tags: magento, magento2

I am looking if Magento can offer me a product type that's can be viewed not downloaded, for example I have a video and I want the user to pay first then he can watch it? is this possible product type in Magento?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not out of the box.

You can make it as a normal product that a user ads to bag and after the customer buys it at checkout you redirect to the page with the video.

Or on success page you will provide them with a link to the video, which is otherwise unreachable. Additionally you can put a check in that page and ask the customer to insert the order number to view it.